# Gridview with Ajax Toolkit CalendarExtender not displaying in Edit Template

Tags: gridview, calendar, extension-methods

I have the folling Gridview column

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Installed Date" SortExpression="install_date">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="gvtxtInstalledDate" runat="server" 
            Text='<%# Bind("install_date") %>'></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:CalendarExtender ID="gvtxtInstalledDate_CalendarExtender" runat="server" 
            Enabled="True" TargetControlID="gvtxtInstalledDate">
        </asp:CalendarExtender>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="gvlblInstallDate" runat="server" 
            Text='<%# Bind("install_date") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

The Calendar extender does not display at all when editing a row item.

EDIT: Doesnt work on any other control either. I do have a script manager in place. The ASP Toolkit is also a part of my website reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed a while ago. The <**asp**:CalendarExtender tag was incorrect, needed to change it to the proper tag prefix.

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>
```

> e.g. <**ajaxToolkit**:CalendarExtender